# Jquery how to query Json Object with multiple where clause

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I query multiple columns/properties from a json object?
I am trying [this](http://jsbin.com/jihofe/1/edit?js,console) to query single column "category". How can Query with both Category and Id?

```
var data = {
  "items": [{
    "id": 1,
    "category": ["cat1","cat2"]
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "category": ["cat1","cat3"]
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "category": ["cat11","cat2"]
  }]
};

var returnedData = $.grep(data.items, function (element) {    
  return element.category.indexOf('cat1') >= 0;
});

console.log(returnedData);
```

Comment: So are you saying that you want to return any objects that have the 'category' of `cat1`? Sorry it's just that I'm a little confused what you want to return

Comment: I am trying to return with a and condition something similar to where cat = 'cat 11' and id= 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the slower `grep`, use plain js `filter`

```js
var data = {
  "items": [{
    "id": 1,
    "category": ["cat1","cat2"]
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "category": ["cat1","cat3"]
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "category": ["cat11","cat2"]
  }]
};

const res = data.items.filter(e => e.category.indexOf('cat1') >= 0 && e.id === 1);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Any performance or other difference with grep and plain filter please?

Comment: [According to this test](https://jsperf.com/grepvsarrayprototypefilter) `$.grep()` is slightly faster.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you are asking but -

```
return element.category.indexOf('cat1') >= 0 && element.id == 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  **return element.category.includes('cat1') && element.id!=1;**
```

This way you can achieve this

```
var data = {
  "items": [{
    "id": 1,
    "category": ["cat1","cat2"]
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "category": ["cat1","cat3"]
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "category": ["cat11","cat2"]
  }]
};

var returnedData = $.grep(data.items, function (element) {    
  return element.category.includes('cat1') && element.id!=1;
});

console.log(returnedData);
```

[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/folimeneho/edit?js,console)